# How to view source code while running iOS app?

Tags: ios

I have a `UIViewController` called simple `ViewController`.  I want it so that when the user presses a button on screen it shows them the code for `ViewController.m`.  How can I do this? I tried

```
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"ViewController.m" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",contents);
```

But it keeps returning `null`Any ideas?

Comment: In order to achieve the result that way, you need to embed the file as a raw data file, not a source file.  When you build your app, the source is compiled, and converted to binary, it isn't simply included in the app, and the processor literally reads your obj-c source code.

Comment: This is a blind shot, but i think you are not referencing your ViewController.m file. In iOS everything is sandbox-ed. So the path to your ViewController may not be where you think it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to package the .m file as a resource to be copied into the main bundle of your application during the appropriate build phase and then read it from the bundle to display.